# Why PDF InputStream.read() returns -1?

Tags: java

I am getting a PDF document from a SOAP response and storing it in a file (even though I don't use it).

```
InputStream in = ( ( InputStream ) att.getContent() );

// TODO For now save in the file system
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream( "Sample.pdf" );

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

// Write the data to the pdf file created
while((read=in.read(bytes))!=-1)
{
    outputStream.write( bytes, 0, read );
}
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

return in;
```

I `return in` directly without closing the connection to another function:

```
DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(submitConnection.getOutputStream()); 

int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while((read = documentInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    dataStream.write(buffer, 0 , read);
}

dataStream.flush();
dataStream.close();
documentInputStream.close();
```

But when I tried this `documentInputStream.read(buffer)` returns -1 so I'm sending empty buffer to the connection `submitConnection`

PS: I debugged and when this happens `documentInputStream` has `count = size of my Sample.pdf` file so I assume this is correct.

**Why can't I read the input stream again and send it to another output stream?**

Comment: Can you use a `BufferedInputStream` object in combination with `mark()` and `reset()`?

Answer (score 1):

The doc says:

> Returns: the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is
>   reached.

means that you've already met the end of the stream, so there nothing more to read in this stream... Either reopen it or rewind it.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: you usually can't rewind or reopen a stream coming in over a network connection.

Comment: @user10628262 if you you have already saved it in a file, then read the file!

Answer (score 0):

You can read a stream only once, as the data falls out of it as you read it.

SOME streams you can rewind to read them again, but streams coming in over a network are not usually of that nature.

What you'd need to do instead is buffer the content somewhere, maybe on a disk file, and then process it from there. This also minimises the time you need to keep your network connection open, often a good thing.